# Clickable hotspots over HTML image

Tags: html, image, area, clickable

Is there any way to create clickable hotspots over a JPEG image in order to navigate to a different image/page? I would like to achieve this without having to code everything in manually and InVision has a lot of limitations.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make parts of an image clickable, just use an image map. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

to do this without coding it in manually you will need some application to make the code for you. it'd be faster for a 1-time use to just set a size for your image, and then make areas (like div's) that are set in place of where it looks like a button on the image, and set their onclick to be a link to your other page or file.